# Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel

Есть билдер запроса:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('first_table ft'))
->join(DB::raw('second_table st'), 'st.id', '=', 'ft.second_id')
->get([
    'ft.id',
    'IF(st.condition IS NULL,0,1) as is_cond',
]);
```

Который выдает ошибку SQL:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4104 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [4104]
```

Из-за того, что полученный запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT [ft].[id], [IF(st].[condition] AS [NULL,0,1)] ...
```

Как можно вставить подобное условие в билдер?

Answer (score 1):

Оберните это условие в `Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;

// ...

DB::table(DB::raw('first_table ft'))
->join(DB::raw('second_table st'), 'st.id', '=', 'ft.second_id')
->get([
    'ft.id',
    new Expression('IF(st.condition IS NULL,0,1) as is_cond'),
]);
```

судя по [бектрейсу](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/35eba4cc2ff84613d606593fa25bfbada7b6048f/Grammar.php#L47) через гитхаб - должно сработать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Чтобы не вставлять use можно использовать DB::raw(), но это не помогло. Видимо проблема кроется глубже. Буду копать дальше.

Comment: версия ларавеля-то какая?

Comment: 3. Да, надо было это написать сразу.

Comment: Может, стоит обновиться? Для третьей версии я даже тег на гитхабе не смог найти.

Comment: Не думаю, что работающий проект можно безболезненно перенести с 3 на 4/5 версию.

Comment: Как видите, безболезненно поддерживать его тоже не получается.